# Find $d$ such that $(M_d, \cdot)$ group is isomorphic to the $(\mathbb{C}^*, \cdot)$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, complex-numbers, group-isomorphism

Let $d$ be an arbitrary real number and
$M_d=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a& db\\
b& a
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R}), \text{where } a^2-db^2\neq 0\right\}.
$

The problem is: show that $(M_d, \cdot)$ is a group("$\cdot$" is here the matrix multiplication), and find the values of $d$ such that $(M_d, \cdot)\cong (\mathbb{C}^*, \cdot)$.

I've managed to show that $(M_d, \cdot)$ is a group, it's just about checking the group axioms. But I can't find the all values of $d$.

I know that it's well-known fact that  $(M_{-1}, \cdot)\cong (\mathbb{C}^*, \cdot)$, where the isomorphism function is just
$
\begin{pmatrix}
a& db\\
b& a
\end{pmatrix}\mapsto a+bi
$, but I have no idea how I can prove that $d=-1$ is only one solution, or find another solutions.

Comment: Why do you think $d=-1$ is the only solution? Did you try other *negative* values of $d$? What about positive values? In that case, can you find a matrix with $A^2 = -1$?

Answer (score 0):

For any non-zero $d,$ consider the map $\varphi_d$ on $M_d$ defined as $\varphi_d:\begin{pmatrix}
a& db\\
b& a
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow a-dbi.$

Then, $\varphi_d$ is clearly surjective. Also, for

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a& db\\
b& a
\end{pmatrix},\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}
x& dy\\
y& x
\end{pmatrix}, $$
we have that
$$\varphi_d(AB)=\varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
ax+dby& day+dbx\\
bx+ay& bdy+ax
\end{pmatrix} \right)=ax+bdy-d(ay+bx)i=(a-dbi)(x-dyi)=\varphi_d(A)\varphi_d(B).$$

So, $\varphi_d$ is an endomorphism between groups, and by the first isomorphism theorem, $M_d/\ker(\varphi_d)\cong C^*.$

Now, $\ker(\varphi_d)$ is those set of matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a& db\\
b& a
\end{pmatrix}$ such that $a-dbi=1.$ Comparing imaginary and real parts, we must have that the kernel has those matrices such that $a=1,b=0,$ that is, the identiy matrix.

Thus, $\ker(\varphi_d)=\{I\}$ and so, $M_d\cong C^*.$

**Exercise:** What about when $d=0?$ Is there an isomorphism?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the calculation, where you showed that the $\varphi_d$ is an endomorphism, with the factorization